# Asterisk autodial some external numbers when joining conference

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to setup an emergency service for our company, and this is the need:

A person that is involved into an emergency situation have to dial a number with his mobile phone and automatically all ermergency squad's people phones will ring and all must be placed in conference call automatically.

I'm near to the solution but I have some difficult with call files , I'm also not sure this is the right way but this is what I made

I've created a conference ( extn 419 )  and also I've created one call file like this

Channel: SIP/123456789@from-internal
MaxRetries: 2
RetryTime: 60
WaitTime: 30
Context: ext-meetme
Extension: 419
Priority: 1

where 123456789 is one of the emergency squad number and 419 is the conference room number

this is working but I have to manually put the call file in the outgoing directory to generate the call
I would like to have the call originate when someone call the 419 extension.

Could someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For your approach you need to trigger AGI script when somebody calls emergency number. And then this script can create call files and copy them to spool directory.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+AGI

If I was building similar solution, then I will probably will do all logic inside AGI script even triggering a call with originate command instead of call files.

My dialpaln:

```
[dialplan-for-emergency]
; 123456 - emergency number
exten => 123456,1,Answer()
exten => 123456,n,AGI(myscript.pl)
exten => 123456,n,Hangup()

myscript.pl # in pseudo code

create conference
create a calls to all other participants into conference
connect callee into conference
```